# How to generate a File Tree in Java Swing directly by providing a absolute path?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

My requirement is that there is a browse button on my UI.When I select a directory and press Open,then using the selected path a tree structure should appear.The parent/root directory will start from the folder that I selected.

Eg: If I select c:/mydocuments/myfiles,then the root for the tree will be myfiles and then it should show all its children in the tree.

Presently in swings JTree can be used to generate a tree structure but for doing this we need to make a list and then supply it to the JTree.

In my scenario,it becomes difficult as everytime I need to generate a list the moment path changes.

So i want to know that in java do we have anything like [jqueryfiletree](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/03/jquery-file-tree/) which takes the absolute path and generates the tree automatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need to make a list. You should just have code that can generate a `TreeModel` based on a file path.

And that code is available on a lot of locations on the internet. For example in [this Sun `JTree` article](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/jtree/)

Another nice example is the ['File Browser GUI'](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4446/file-browser-gui/4451#4451) from Andrew Thompson who is also active on this site

Answer (score 4):

Here is a minimal working code sample:

```
public class FileTree extends JTree
{   
   public FileTree(String path)
   {
      super(scan(new File(path)));
   }

   private static MutableTreeNode scan(File node)
   {
      DefaultMutableTreeNode ret = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(node.getName());
      if (node.isDirectory())
         for (File child: node.listFiles())
            ret.add(scan(child));
      return ret;
   }
}
```